# passage from C to K

Tags: history

I happened to notice in Köpenick that the name of the city was spelt Cöpenick in an old street sign. Was there a general passage from C to K at some time in the history of the german language ?

Comment: ... It was formerly known as Copanic and then Cöpenick, only officially adopting the current spelling in 1931. ... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Köpenick

Answer (score 3):

According to the German Wikipedia, the [spelling reform of 1901](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthographische_Konferenz_von_1901) changed the spelling of a number of city names (but not all) from C to K, such as Kassel or Köln, but not Coburg or Cottbus. The article does not explicitly refer to the name Köpenick.

Comment: general also concerns names and things ;)

Comment: Das zugehörige Tor bzw. der verbliebene Platz in Berlin heißt jedoch "Kottbusser Tor".

Comment: @userunknown Das wollte ich auch gerade erwähnen. Cottbuss sollte wohl auch ein K bekommen, aber es hat sich nicht durchgesetzt.